Single 4x4:4 MU-MIMO vs Two 2x2:2 MU-MIMO APs
Just out of curiosity, in general, what would be the pros and cons of having a single 4x4:4 MU-MIMO AP vs having two 2x2:2 MU-MIMO APs in the same network? (Assume that they are the same brand with similar spec and the price of entire installation between the two options is exactly equal.)
My thought is, in a real-world enterprise usage where there must be multiple of APs in the same space. The 4x4 AP may use only a single frequency channel and the two 2x2 APs will require two channels. Having lesser amount of APs may help reduce the amount of channel collision.
What are your thoughts when picking between the two for an enterprise installation?
